# modify a listview content from a another window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

i'm coding in c#/wpf (i'm a beginner), i have 2 windows:
window1 contains a listview , window2 contains  textboxes in which i retrieve their values  to do some treatement to obtain in the end a list(collection that i created) in window2 and the problem is that :
i want to fill my listview (window1) from window2 with the iformations obtained from the collection (window2); but i can't
code window1

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                        
    }

private void Ajouter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 a = new Window1();
        a.List_inf = new List<Listview_content>();
        viewMed.ItemsSource = a.List_inf;            
        a.Show();
    }
```

code window2

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public  List<Listview_content> list_inf;
    public List<Listview_content> List_inf
    {
        get { return list_inf; }
        set { list_inf = value; }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void valider_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    Listview_content med_inf = new Listview_content();
        med_inf.marque = "marque";
        med_inf.restitue = true;
        med_inf.quant = 40;
        med_inf.prix = 14;
        list_inf.Add(med_inf); 
}
```

Comment: Declare `Window2 mywindow= new Window2` , then u can access it :)

Comment: i did ..... well I forgot to mention that in the code window 1 is MainWindow and window 2 is window1

Comment: ow....then ,, if the window1 is the startup form, you cannot use a new instance of it ..Rather,go with data binding

Comment: can you tell me how to do that exactly please! because i used data binding before and it didn't work.

Comment: ever used `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?? or u can go with a timer as well

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution :)

**In Window2 create a list**

```
public class window2
{
public List<string> ItemList = new List<string>;
public void btn_Add()
{
    ItemList.Add("StringHere");
}
}
```

**In Window1**

```
public class window1
{
Window2 win2 = new Window2;
public void btn_Click()
{
    win2.showDialog();
    foreach (var item in win2.ItemList)
    {
        combobox1.Items.Add(item.tostring);
    }
}
}
```